# GDB fails to download debuginfo for math.h

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a simple clock program that uses `math.h` functions. I am currently on `Kubuntu 21.10`, the GCC version is `(Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0`, and the GDB version is `(Ubuntu 12.1-3ubuntu2) 12.1`.

The program source code (although it might not be needed):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "conio.h"
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
#define RAD_90 1.570796 // precomputed value of 90 degrees in radians
#define RAD_30 0.523599 // precomputed value of 30 degrees in radians
#define RAD_6 0.104720 // precomputed value of 6 degree in radians
#define RAD_1 0.017453 // precomputed value of 1 degree in radians

#define X 0 // x co-ordinate in array
#define Y 1 // y co-ordinate in array

int COLUMNS, ROWS;

#define CLOCK_RADIUS (COLUMNS/2)-1

#define FPS 24
#define MOVE_TO_HOME() (printf("\033[H"))
#define CLEAR_TERMINAL_SCREEN() (printf("\033[2J"))
#define cls() (CLEAR_TERMINAL_SCREEN())

void die(const char *s) {
    cls();
    printf("clock: error: %s: ", s);
    fflush(stdout);
    perror(NULL);
    fflush(stderr);
    exit(1);
}

char **output/*[ROWS][COLUMNS*2]*/;
struct tm *t = NULL;

void get_window_size(int *rows, int *cols) {;
    struct winsize ws;

    if(ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws) == -1 || ws.ws_col == 0) {
        if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[999C\x1b[999B", 12) != 12) die("write");
        fflush(stdout);

        char buf[32];
        unsigned int i = 0;

        if(write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[6n", 4) != 4) die("write");
        printf("\r\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        while(i < (sizeof(buf)-1)) {
            if(read(STDIN_FILENO, &buf[i], 1) != 1) die("read");
            if(buf[i] == 'R') break;
            i++;
        }
        buf[i] = '\0';

        if((buf[0] != '\x1b') || (buf[1] != '[')) die("\\x1b[6n read failure");
        if(sscanf(&buf[2], "%d;%d", rows, cols) != 2) die("sscanf(146)");

        cls();
    } else {
        *cols = ws.ws_col;
        *rows = ws.ws_row;
    }
}

void print_char(char c, int x, int y) {
    if((x >= 0) && (y >= 0) && (x < COLUMNS) && (y < ROWS)) {
        output[y][x*2] = c;
    }
}

double deg_to_rad(int deg) {
    return deg*PI/180;
}

void clear_buffer() {
    for(int i = 0;i < ROWS;i++) {
        memset(output[i], ' ', COLUMNS*2);
    }
    output[ROWS-1][COLUMNS*2] = '\0';
}

void print_buffer() {
    for(int i = 0;i < ROWS;i++) {
        puts(output[i]);
    }
}

void print_circle(char body, int r, int center[]) {
    if(r == 0) {
        print_char(body, center[X], center[Y]);
        return;
    }

    int offset[2], prev_offset[2] = {-1, -1};
    double ang = 0, ang_leap;

    ang_leap = deg_to_rad((1*360)/(2*PI*r));

    if(ang_leap > RAD_1) {
        ang_leap = RAD_1;
    } else if(ang_leap == 0) {
        ang_leap = 0.0001;
    }

    while(ang <= RAD_90) {
        offset[X] = round(sin(ang)*r);
        offset[Y] = round(cos(ang)*r);

        if((offset[X] == prev_offset[X]) && (offset[Y] == prev_offset[Y])) {
            ang += ang_leap;
            continue;
        }

        print_char(body, center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]+offset[Y]); // 1st quadrant

        print_char(body, center[X]-offset[X], center[Y]+offset[Y]); // 2nd quadrant

        print_char(body, center[X]-offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]); // 3rd quadrant

        print_char(body, center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]); // 4th quadrant

        prev_offset[X] = offset[X];
        prev_offset[Y] = offset[Y];

        ang += ang_leap;
    }
}

void print_numbers(int r, int center[]) {
    /*
    *      deg_to_rad(360/NUM_OF_NUMBERS) = ang
    *   => deg_to_rad(360/12) = ang
    *   => ang = deg_to_rad(30)
    *
    *
    *      sin(ang) = P/H
    *   =  sin(ang)*H = P
    *
    *   => offset_x = sin(ang)*r
    *      offset_y = cos(ang)*r
    */

    int offset[2];

    for(int i = 1;i <= 12;i++) {
        offset[X] = round(sin(RAD_30*i)*r);
        offset[Y] = round(cos(RAD_30*i)*r);

        if(i >= 10) {
            print_char((i/10)+'0', center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]);
            print_char((i%10)+'0', center[X]+offset[X]+1, center[Y]-offset[Y]);
        } else {
            print_char(i+'0', center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]);
        }
    }
}

void print_hands(int r, int center[], struct tm t) {
    int len, offset[2];
    double ang, sin_value, cos_value;
    char body;

    // second hand
    body = '.';
    len = (r*80)/100;

    ang = t.tm_sec*RAD_6;

    sin_value = sin(ang);
    cos_value = cos(ang);

    for(int i = 0;i <= len;i++) {
        offset[X] = round(sin_value*i);
        offset[Y] = round(cos_value*i);

        print_char(body, center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]);
    }

    // minute hand
    body = '*';
    len = (r*65)/100;

    ang = deg_to_rad((t.tm_min*6)/*+(t.tm_sec/10)*/); // seconds adjustement causes confusion

    sin_value = sin(ang);
    cos_value = cos(ang);

    for(int i = 0;i <= len;i++) {
        offset[X] = round(sin_value*i);
        offset[Y] = round(cos_value*i);

        print_char(body, center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]);
    }

    // hour hand
    body = '@';
    len = (r*40)/100;

    ang = deg_to_rad((t.tm_hour*30)+(t.tm_min/2)+(t.tm_sec/120));

    sin_value = sin(ang);
    cos_value = cos(ang);

    for(int i = 0;i <= len;i++) {
        offset[X] = round(sin_value*i);
        offset[Y] = round(cos_value*i);

        print_char(body, center[X]+offset[X], center[Y]-offset[Y]);
    }
}

struct tm *get_time() {
    time_t seconds = time(NULL);

    if(seconds == -1) {
        perror("error while calling function time()");
        return NULL;
    }

    struct tm *tm = localtime(&seconds);

    if(tm == NULL) {
        perror("error while calling function localtime()");
        return NULL;
    }

    return tm;
}

int print_clock() {
    int center[] = {COLUMNS/2, ROWS/2};

    print_circle('.', CLOCK_RADIUS, center);
    print_numbers(CLOCK_RADIUS, center);

    t = get_time();
    if(t == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    print_hands(CLOCK_RADIUS, center, *t);

    print_char('@', center[X], center[Y]);

    return 0;
}

void print_centered(int col_size, char *str) {
    int str_len = strlen(str);
    int start_pos = col_size-(str_len/2);
    for(int i = 0;i < start_pos;i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}

int main() {
    get_window_size(&ROWS, &COLUMNS);
    if(ROWS > COLUMNS/2) {
        COLUMNS -= 2;
        COLUMNS /= 2;
        ROWS = COLUMNS;
    } else if(COLUMNS/2 > ROWS) {
        ROWS -= 2;
        COLUMNS = ROWS;
    }
    output = malloc(sizeof(char*)*ROWS);
    for(int i = 0;i < ROWS;i++) {
        output[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*((COLUMNS*2)+1));
    }
    CLEAR_TERMINAL_SCREEN();

    while(!kbhit()) {
        MOVE_TO_HOME();

        clear_buffer();

        if(print_clock()) {
            return 1;
        }

        print_buffer();

        print_centered(COLUMNS, asctime(t));

        usleep((1000*1000)/FPS);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < ROWS;i++) {
        free(output[i]);
    }
    free(output);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program with `gcc clock.c -lm -g`, and run it with `gdb ./a.out`, I allow `gdb` to download debug info from `https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com`. I set breakpoint at `line 175` (which uses `sin` function), then enter `step` and I see this error:

```gdb
Breakpoint 1, print_hands (r=17, center=0x7fffffffda20, t=...) at clock.c:175
175             sin_value = sin(ang);
(gdb) step
__sin_fma (x=0.83775999999999995) at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c:201
Download failed: Invalid argument.  Continuing without source file ./math/../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c.
201     ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c: No such file or directory.
```

As I see, it fails to download debug info for `sin` function here. I tried searching the internet for similar questions, but couldn't find anything similar.

What is the problem here with my `gdb` and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info you need is not in the math.h header file, it's in the source code of the C standard library. Unfortunately, as noted in the [Service - Debuginfod](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-debuginfod) documentation, the Ubuntu Debuginfod service currently does not provide that:

> Currently, the service only provides DWARF information. There are
> plans to make it also index and serve source-code in the future.

You can however download the source code to a local directory, and point gdb to that via the `dir` command (or its `-d` command line equivalent). Ex. given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  double x = atof(argv[1]);

  double y = sin(x);

  printf("sin(%.3f) = %.3f\n", x, y);

  return(0);
}
```

then

```
mkdir -p src && cd src 
apt-get source libc6
cd ..

gcc -g -o myprog myprog.c -lm

DEBUGINFOD_URLS="https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com" gdb -d ./src/glibc-2.35 myprog
```

results in the following interactive session

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1

[copyright header skipped]

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from myprog...
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11b8: file myprog.c, line 8.
(gdb) r 3.14
Starting program: /home/steeldriver/myprog 3.14

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n]) y
Debuginfod has been enabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled on' to .gdbinit.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdf98) at myprog.c:8
8         double y = sin(x);
(gdb) s
__sin_avx (x=3.1400000000000001) at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c:201
201     {
(gdb)
```